# How many connections will be build btween spark and hdfs when sc.textFile("hdfs://.....") is called

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

How many connections will be build btween spark and hdfs when sc.textFile("hdfs://.....") is called. The file on hdfs is very large(100G).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the main idea behind the distributed systems and of course which is designed and implemented in hadoop and spark is to send the process to data. In other words, imagine that there is some data located on hdfs data nodes on our cluster and we have a job which utilizes that data on the same worker. On each machine, you would have a data node and is a spark worker at the same time and may have some other processes like hbase region server too. When an executor is executing one of the scheduled tasks, it retrieves its needed data from the underlying data node. Then for each individual task you would retrieve its data and so you may describe this as one connection to hdfs on its local data node.